# Scodec combinators: Header contains magic number that is used to discriminate types

Tags: scala, scodec

I am looking for a way to approach a protocol like the following example:

```
case class Request(bodyType: Int, foo: Int, bar: Int, body: RequestBody)

sealed trait RequestBody
case class Read(key: String) extends RequestBody
case class Write(key: String, value: Array[Byte]) extends RequestBody
```

Here, `bodyType == 0` will stand for `Read`, and `bodyType != 0` will encode `Write`.
Note that there are a few fields separating discriminator from discriminated value.

I've seen [an example with byte-ordering](https://youtu.be/jM21a-t4JnQ?t=18m43s).
But as far as I understand this "squid" encoded discriminator would not round trip. 
What's the correct way to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, but this is one I've used:

```
import scodec._
import scodec.codecs._
import scodec.bits._

case class Request(bodyType: Int, foo: Int, bar: Int, body: RequestBody)

sealed trait RequestBody
case class Read(key: String) extends RequestBody
object Read {
  implicit val codec: Codec[Read] = ("key" | utf8).as[Read]
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[RequestBody, Read, Int] = Discriminator(0)
}
case class Write(key: String, value: ByteVector) extends RequestBody
object Write {
  implicit val codec: Codec[Write] = {
    ("key"   | utf8  ) ::
    ("value" | bytes )
  }.as[Write]
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[RequestBody, Write, Int] = Discriminator(1)
}

object Request {
  implicit val codec: Codec[Request] = {
    ("bodyType" | uint16 ).flatPrepend { bodyType =>
    ("foo"      | uint16 ) ::
    ("bar"      | uint16 ) ::
    ("body"     | Codec.coproduct[RequestBody].discriminatedBy(provide(bodyType)).auto)
  }}.as[Request]
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I have some issues with `ByteVector` roundtrip, but overall works like a charm

Comment: Turns out I had this problem because of `utf8`, which redirects to `string` and [one cannot simply use `string` if it's not the very last field](https://github.com/scodec/scodec/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/scodec/codecs/package.scala#L488-L493)

Comment: sorry, i should have constrained it with fixedSizeBytes(5, utf8) (or whatever the size of your string is) otherwise it'll keep consuming bytes until it hits a non-utf8 encoded byte or the input bits are exhausted as you indicate). But glad it worked for you.